# VsCode hangs/freezes with "Starting up powershell" in status bar

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code, freeze, vscode-debugger

Sometimes starting up VsCode to debug a file, the PowerShell extension hangs and the VsCode terminal Window has a status bar message `Starting PowerShell`. It never times out and it never crashes, it just stays stuck at **Starting PowerShell**:

<sub>There's going to be various answers to this question.. let me start with two solution that have worked for me.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **all other Powershell windows are closed**.

*Confirm that all Powershell processes are terminated in the relevant OS, eg Task Manager in windows.*

Start VsCode running as Admin.

---

If you get prompted to update the Package Manager do so:

`powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command 'Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Force -MinimumVersion 1.4.6 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber'`

---

If that fails, in the Terminal run a Powershell command, eg

`Get-PSRepository`

That will complete the "Starting Powerhell" and in the status bar you will see the Powershell version.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I did steps and still powershell is starting

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and comparing the $PSModulePath value on a system where VSCode was working I found that the working system had %ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules and %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules as the first and second entries. I updated my broken system to match and magically my vscode powershell extension worked like normal.